# How to replace “35yrs” with “35 yrs” using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

This question is about Search & Replace.

I have a list that looks like this:

> 35yrs
>
> 74 yrs
>
> 40yrs
>
> 24yrs
>
> 36 yrs

I want to use regular expressions to make the list look like this:

> 35 yrs
>
> 74 yrs
>
> 40 yrs
>
> 24 yrs
>
> 36 yrs

I have this for the search:

```regex
\d+[y][r][s]
```

What should the replace string look like? Textmate's search engine requires numbers in the result, e.g., $1, that represent the regex in the search field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no reason for `[…]` around individual letters — ever.

For your expression, just capture the digits:

```
(\d+)\s?yrs
```

And replace them:

```
\1 yrs
```

Strictly speaking matching the space (`\s?`) is unnecessary: if you do not include it, those entries that already include a space will not be matched, which is fine: theyʼre already correct, after all.

Answer (score 3):

Capture with:

```
 *(yrs)
```

and replace with:

```
 \1
```

Note the leading whitespace in both match and replacement. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/tUOiNl/1).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex:

```
(\d+)\s*(yrs)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1 $2
```

---

This matches the number in the first capturing group (indicated with `()`) and the `yrs` in the second. The replacement is then both capturing groups with a space between. The whitespace is not matched in between the two capturing groups and is optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java,  you can do it like so.

```
String str = "35yrs";
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+)\\s*yrs)", "$1 yrs);
```

Changes years followed by zero or more spaces and `yrs` to years followed by one space followed by `yrs`.